# How to solve linear equations as string using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

x, y = symbols('x y')

eq1 = Eq(x+y, 5)
eq2 = Eq(x-y, -3)

solve((eq1,eq2), (x, y))
sol_dict = solve((eq1,eq2), (x, y))

print(f'x = {sol_dict[x]}')
print(f'y = {sol_dict[y]}')
```

I am taking two linear equations as string

```
# x+y=5
# x-y=-3
```

but `Eq()` not accepting a string how can I achieve this.
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be helpful you can try with this...

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

x, y = symbols('x y')
string_1 = 'x+y=5'
string_2 = 'x-y=-3'
eq1 = Eq(eval(string_1.split('=')[0]), int(string_1.split('=')[-1]))
eq2 = Eq(eval(string_2.split('=')[0]), int(string_2.split('=')[-1]))

solve((eq1,eq2), (x, y))
sol_dict = solve((eq1,eq2), (x, y))

print(f'x = {sol_dict[x]}')
print(f'y = {sol_dict[y]}')
```